# Discord.py raise RuntimeError('Task is already launched and is not completed.')

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 94, in on_ready
    update_fetch.start()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 205, in start

raise RuntimeError('Task is already launched and is not completed.')

RuntimeError: Task is already launched and is not completed.
```

Does anyone know why this keeps going on? My bot has been running fine for 1 month then suddenly it appears like this every once in a while, although it only affects the status of the bot,  all the bot functions are fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you start the task in `on_ready`, which could be called multiplie times, when `on_ready` is called the second time, you get this error.
To prevent this, you could simply check if the task is already started:

```py
#change update_fetch.start() to:
if not update_fetch.is_running():
    update_fetch.start()
```

**Sources:**

- [on_ready](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_ready)
- [is_running](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.is_running)

If this doesn't work for you, could you include the code of `on_ready` and `update_fetch` in your post