# Discord.py Error While Status Changing every 10 minutes

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Hi so im making a bot that changes the status every 10 minutes or so with different activites. Only problem its givng me a strange error. I tried changing Activit to Activity but it will give me a Runtime Error saying the task was launched and not completed. Then i have to run one of the bots commands again and it will post the message but it still wont change the status
Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    activity.start()

@tasks.loop(minutes=10)
async def activity():
 await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activit(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=data))
```

```
Error:
  File "main.py", line 38, in activity
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activit(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=parsing_data))
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Activit'
```

Comment: There's a typo in `await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activit(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=data))`: it's "Activity" and not "Activit". It's anyways not going to work with "Activit".

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder please read my full question

Comment: Please post the error you get when you change it to "Activity".

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder I dont need to please read full question

Comment: "the task was launched and not completed." - is this all you get?

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder yes basicallyt

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68125842/16136190) help? `activity.start()` isn't `await`ed. You have to add `await` before `activity.start()`, since `on_ready()` has `async`. So, your `on_ready()` will be: `await activity.start()`.

Comment: Also, change "Activit" to "Activity".

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder since when `activity.start` is a coroutine? It's not meant to be awaited.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński, sorry, I hadn't tested it then, but the code works fine for me and doesn't show any errors after changing "Activit" to "Activity". All parts of the posted code work fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `discord.activit` to `discord.Activity`. You've made a typo in your code. I think the error clearly says that.

Comment: Please read full question